# Java : calculate remaining time compared to current time

Tags: java

I have a string in format :

```
2015-10-01 02:00
```

I want to print the remaining time compared to current time in Java, it should print in format :

```
It remains 1 day 4 hours 25 minutes
```

How could I do that ? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Okay, so there's a lot of steps involved in that - parsing the target, finding out the current time, working out the difference, and then formatting it. Which step is causing you problems, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working! Could you withdraw all the unvotes please ?

```
public static void calculateRemainTime(String scheduled_date){

    // date format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    // two dates
    java.util.Date scheduledDate;
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date currentDate;
    String current_date = format.format(current.getTime());
        try {
            scheduledDate = format.parse(scheduled_date);
            currentDate = format.parse(current_date);
            long diffInMillies = scheduledDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
            long diffence_in_minute = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println(diffence_in_minute);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```